# Google sheets script to sort rows imported from another tab by column

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

I am new to scripting in google sheets and I am trying to add a function in a script to sort a range by column value in ascending order.

I'm using a script that allows me to move rows from one tab to another based on payment status. All imported rows are placed in row 7, just below the header. As a result, the lines are completely messy.

I have tried so many things that I am lost. I don't know if I've tried the wrong function or if I'm placing them in the wrong place in the script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if (sh.getName()=='Suivi Clients' && rng.getColumn()==21){
    if(rng.getValue()=='OUI' || rng.getValue()=='ANNULÉ'){

      var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Clients Finalisé')
      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      var plage = sh.getRange('C' + rng.getRow() + ':G'  + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('L' + rng.getRow() + ':N'  + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('U' + rng.getRow() + ':W'  + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
    }
  }

  if (sh.getName()=='Clients Finalisé' && rng.getColumn()==21){
    if(rng.getValue()=='NON'){

      var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Suivi Clients')
      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      var plage = sh.getRange('C' + rng.getRow() + ':G'  + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('L' + rng.getRow() + ':N'  + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('U' + rng.getRow() + ':W'  + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
    }
  }

  // other onEdit here
}
```

Dans l'onglet "Suivi Clients" je voudrais trier par colonne G et dans l'onglet "Clients Finalisé" je voudrais trier par colonne P.

That's one of the functions I tried:

```
function sort() {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Suivi Clients");
       var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W");
       range.sort(7);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function sortSC() { // Suivi Clients
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Suivi Clients");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({column:7,ascending:true});
}

function sortCF() { // Clients Finalisé
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients Finalisé");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({column:16,ascending:true});
}

Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function (col) { 
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  if (col == null) { col = 1 }
  var range = this.getRange(lastRow, col);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }
};
```

FYI, complete script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if (sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' && rng.getColumn() == 21) {
    if (rng.getValue() == 'OUI' || rng.getValue() == 'ANNULÉ') {

      var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Clients Finalisé')
      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      var plage = sh.getRange('C' + rng.getRow() + ':G' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('L' + rng.getRow() + ':N' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('U' + rng.getRow() + ':W' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortCF()
    }
  }

  if (sh.getName() == 'Clients Finalisé' && rng.getColumn() == 21) {
    if (rng.getValue() == 'NON') {

      var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Suivi Clients')
      dest.insertRowBefore(7)

      var plage = sh.getRange('C' + rng.getRow() + ':G' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('L' + rng.getRow() + ':N' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('P' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
      var plage = sh.getRange('U' + rng.getRow() + ':W' + rng.getRow())
      plage.copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)

      sh.deleteRow(rng.getRow())
      SpreadsheetApp.flush()
      sortSC()
    }
  }

  if (sh.getName() != 'Suivi Clients') return;
  var editRange = {
    top: 6,
    left: 3,
    right: 7
  };
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;
  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;
  removeEmpty()
}

function sortSC() { // Suivi Clients
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Suivi Clients");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({ column: 7, ascending: true });
}

function sortCF() { // Clients Finalisé
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clients Finalisé");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastDataRow(3)));
  range.sort({ column: 16, ascending: true });
}

Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function (col) {
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  if (col == null) { col = 1 }
  var range = this.getRange(lastRow, col);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried to past this code to the top of my code before onEdit but it not work..

Comment: include sortCF() and sortSC() inside onEdit after a flush()

Comment: Either it doesn't work or I'm placing it wrong

Comment: Copied and pasted like this sort is not working

Comment: And also my first script to delete empty rows not works anymore

Comment: for sorting, I have inverted the functions

Comment: Now all is working. Thank you Mike

Answer (score 1):

#### Sort a range ascending

```
function sort() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Suivi Clients");
  var range = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + (sheet.getLastRow()-5));
  range.sort({column:7,ascending:true});
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Suivi Clients' && e.range.getColumn() == 21) {
    if (e.range.getValue() == 'OUI' || e.range.getValue() == 'ANNULÉ') {
      var dest = e.source.getSheetByName('Clients Finalisé');
      dest.insertRowBefore(7)
      sh.getRange('C' + e.range.rowStart + ':G' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      sh.getRange('L' + e.range.rowStart + ':N' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      sh.getRange('P' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      sh.getRange('U' + e.range.rowStart + ':W' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    }
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Clients Finalisé' && e.range.getColumn() == 21 && e.value == 'NON') {
    var dest = e.source.getSheetByName('Suivi Clients')
    dest.insertRowBefore(7);
    sh.getRange('C' + e.range.rowStart + ':G' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    sh.getRange('L' + e.range.rowStart + ':N' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("L7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    sh.getRange('P' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("P7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    sh.getRange('U' + e.range.rowStart + ':W' + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("U7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

This sort sorts the values in the array and then using setValues it places the values back into the spreadsheet.  If you are using formulas in this range then it could damage the formulas. It also assumes that the values in column7 within the range are all dates.

```
function sort() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var vs = sheet.getRange("B6:W" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  vs.sort((a, b) => {
    let vA = new Date(a[5]).valueOf();
    let vB = new Date(b[5]).valueOf();
    return vA - vB;
  })
  sheet.getRange("B6:W" + sheet.getLastRow()).setValues(vs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, and I can insert this function in my script or I have to add a new script in my project?

Comment: Your question indicated to me that you did not know how to sort a range.  This is how you sort a range.  As for the rest of your script I don't wish to have anything to do with it.  It's a mess.

Comment: It's not a mess, it's very clear and it works very well. I just need to insert a function to sort. I think you don't understand what I needed when I made this script.

Comment: You might consider  `sh.getRange('C' + e.range.rowStart + ':G'  + e.range.rowStart).copyTo(dest.getRange("C7"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);`

Comment: Ok yes it work but the sort function not..

Comment: I don't know if it can be the reason but I already have onEdit function in another script. I put it at the end of your script.

Comment: I just tested it on one of my sheets and it's working for me.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning for putting an onEdit function inside or a sort function.  That seems wierd to me.

Comment: So It's the combination of your onEdit and my sort function that's not working.  I'd recommend removing your onEdit and test it again.

Comment: Because I have another script running with onEdit who delete empty rows in tab Suivi Clients

Comment: I removed onEdit downstairs of your srcipt but sort still not working. Moving rows is working. I can't delete the first script who delete rows because I need it

Comment: Well I tested it on my sheets and it works.  If you can provide before and after examples then I can assist you more.

Comment: All your script copied and pasted in appscript, moving row is working but sort not. I added only sort function in one script and executed it, it work. Values in G column are date, I don't know if it's important to know..